# How do I Create Several NoSQL Stores and Access Them (Flutter/Dart)?

Tags: database, flutter, dart, nosql, sembast

I am trying to use Sembast as a local database for an app but I am having trouble creating and accessing different "stores" in the database.

So far, I can initialize and access a single store but I want to be able to create 3 different stores and access each of them when needed. My code so far is shown below:

Creating the database and unique store:

```
class SembastActivityRepository extends ActivityRepository {
  final String activityName; //available paths are log, user_preferences,
  final StoreRef<int, Map<String, dynamic>> _store;
  final Database _database = GetIt.I.get();

  SembastActivityRepository({this.activityName})
      : _store = intMapStoreFactory.store(activityName);

  @override
  Future<int> insertActivity(Activity activity) async {
    return await _store.add(_database, activity.toMap());
  }

  @override
  Future updateActivity(Activity activity) async {
    await _store.record(activity.id).update(_database, activity.toMap());
  }
...
}
```

Initializing the database and store titled "Sleep":

```
class Init {
  //final String activityName;
  //Init(this.activityName);

  static Future initialize() async {
    //initialize Sembast database
    final appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    await appDir.create(recursive: true);
    final databasePath = join(appDir.path, "sembast.db");
    final database = await databaseFactoryIo.openDatabase(databasePath);
    GetIt.I.registerSingleton<Database>(database);

    //register Repository
    GetIt.I.registerLazySingleton<ActivityRepository>(
        () => SembastActivityRepository(activityName: 'Sleep'));
  }
...
}
```

How would I be able to create 3 unique stores and later be able to switch between accessing the data in the stores (say by pressing a button I can cycle through the data in the stores)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

A store is just a definition with a name and type of key and value used. You can simply declare multiple stores in your `SembastActivityRepository` class or create multiple subclasses with a different activityName (which sounds like the name of the store you use).

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! I don't quite understand what you mean by declaring multiple stores in the SembastActivityRepository. Would it be like: final StoreRef<int, Map<String, dynamic>> _store1;
final StoreRef<int, Map<String, dynamic>> _store2; and would this mean I would have to put the stores as an input to the functions such as updateActivity, deleteActivity, etc?

Comment: I am able to create different stores like 'Sleep' and 'Exercise' by modifying the string in the Init class but switching folders requires me to restart the app completely. Is there a way to do this within the app once I have declared multiple stores?

Comment: Hard to say as this sounds specific to your application. I'm not used to GetIt and how it works and whether that is the proper way to retrieve the proper class in your case.

Answer (score 2):

how about creating them using :

```
final sleepDbStore = sembast.intMapStoreFactory.store('sleep');
final sweetDreamsDbStore = sembast.intMapStoreFactory.store('sweetDreams');
final nightmaresDbStore = sembast.intMapStoreFactory.store('nightmares');
```

[sembast recommended way to create a store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63036789/sembast-recommended-way-to-create-a-store)