# sembast recommended way to create a store

Tags: flutter, sembast

I am confused by the fact that there are two ways to create a Store :

```dart
var store = sembast.StoreRef<String, List<dynamic>>.main();
await store.record('username').put(db, 'my_username');
```

```dart
final usernameDbStore = sembast.intMapStoreFactory.store('username');
```

Is the 1st (.main) meant to keep the .db settings ?
Is there another difference between the two ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `main()` is just a convenient shortcut to a store named `_main`. Some applications sometimes need a single store so don't bother about giving it a name.

An application can have multiple named stores too (_main + some others). There is no difference in using `_main` vs another store nor any guidelines/recommendations. Typically, I personnally have a store named `prefs` for my application preferences or singletons and then one store per entity type (notes, contacts...).

Comment: Thank you for your quick and clear response (my SO profile is too low profile to +1 it yet).
The 2nd method is already very convenient. If an app only needs a single store, it could create it through the 2nd way. It seems there is room to establish a standard.
Such guidelines would make it easier to adopt sembast and speed up adoption time.

Comment: intMapStoreFactory is a shortcut for `<int, Map<String, dynamic>>` which is sometimes a pain to write. That is typically what i use. If your want to specify a different type for key and value such as `<String, String>` then you need to specify them using StoreRef constructor. I understand the confusion and will try to add some doc on that. Even you if you cannot +1 yet, I guess you can accept the answer! thanks!